# What type of java project can serve web services?

Tags: java, web-services

Do I have been writing a java application, application is a console application.

Now, I want my application to listen to request at a port coming from web application and process those request and affect DB data.

I am not sure how to do it in  a simple java project. Can I use some java webservices, and how?

Answer (score 1):

Socket programming in Java is quite nice - a Socket is an abstraction that listens for data coming in on a single port from a single web address or server and can also send out.

http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html

Note that listening for data blocks program flow.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're looking at learning [Java Servlet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html) programming. There are a lot of good resources to learn from.

However, from my experience something like [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) could serve you really well from both learning and actual application development perspectives. The site contains very reasonable example driven documentation, which takes user from non-blocking TCP/IP programming to HTTP support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , web service  API (JAX-WS 2.0) is added to the Java SE 6. You can use these API to create a simple web service for the  Java SE application.

See the section ["Using JAX-WS 2.0 to Create a Simple Web Service"](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) for the example .It shows how to create a standard web service end-point using JAX-WS 2.0 for the  Java SE application.

Beside , [this 5 minutes tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world)  is very good at introducing JAX-WS .It includes the demo for implementing the web-service end-point and client and provide the eclipse project source code to download too. Please note that it misses the step to use  `wsgen`  to generate the service classes for the WebService end-point ,but it is not so difficult to figure out how to use `wsgen`

Comment: +1 for Jax-ws. It makes building soap services a breeze. For REST however, I prefer Jersey.